# Magento: How to get the id of the just duplicated product programmatically

Tags: magento

How can I get the id of the just duplicated product programmatically in Magento ?

(or the last inserted product id, if the first solution don't exits)

Thanks for help.

**[EDIT]**

Here is the code that I have used to duplicate my product:

```
$sku = '123456';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
   ->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); 

$newProduct = $product->duplicate();
$newProduct->setStatus(1);
$newProduct->setSku($sku.'-v2');
$newProduct->save();
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you give more information. Are you doing this in the Admin panel, or programaticaly?

Comment: I'm doing it programmatically, thanks for help

Comment: Can you post the code you're using for product cloning?

Comment: @WojtekT: I have modified the question, with the code that I have used.

Comment: Does this work? `$newId = $newProduct->getId();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the new prodect ID in:

```
$newProduct->getId()
```

This is available just after calling :

```
$newProduct = $product->duplicate();
```

FYI: to get the last insertedId (in general) you can use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchOne('SELECT last_insert_id()')
```

Comment: and not after ´$newProduct->save();´ ??

Comment: of course it is! but is available since you call `$product->duplicate()`